# Extracting climate and soil data for longitude-latitude points

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, r-raster

I would like to obtain climate and soil information for GPS locations in the EU for 2006 to 2016.

I looked into Worldclim, however, the records seem to stop in 2010. For soil information, I would like to use the European Soil Database v2.0 which provides raster files. Unfortunately, I do not know how to extract values from a raster file. For climate information, I tried using RNCEP, however, I cannot find information regarding this error

> Error in strsplit(grep("missing_value", x=readLines(scale.offset.missingvals.temp),  : 
>     subscript out of bounds

```
library(RNCEP)
dat <- NCEP.gather(variable='air', level=850, months.minmax=c(1,12), 
years.minmax=c(2006,2016), lat.southnorth=c(51,53), 
lon.westeast=c(4,5),reanalysis2 = FALSE, return.units = TRUE)
```

The answer would briefly describe how to extract values for points from a raster file and how I obtain information on temperature and rainfall for 2006 to 2016.

Comment: The website is down due to the partial closure of the U.S. Government. 


There is probably nothing wrong with your code.  https://governmentshutdown.noaa.gov/

Comment: I was delusional enough to think Trump wont affect me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use raster::extract

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
xy <- cbind(-50, seq(-80, 80, by=20))

extract(r, xy)
#[1] 626 554 482 410 338 266 194 122  50
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment @RobertHijmans. I tried using the extract function, however, it always returns NA. 

My raster 
class: RasterLayer 
dimensions: 5500, 7500, 41250000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution: 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent: 0, 7500000, 0, 5500000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref.: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
values: 2, 131  (min, max)
attributes: ID  COUNT    WRBFU
 from:   2 131617 3 3 33 3
 to  : 131    116       SC

Comment: and some test points
class: SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features: 2 
extent: 5.36, 5.67, 51.48, 51.81  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref.: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables: 1
names:  id 
min values: lat 
max values: lon

Comment: Given its extent, `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84` is clearly wrong for your RasterLayer. But the extent itself is also fishy, for starting at zero. You need to find out what the true extent and/or crs is, and, if the crs is not lonlat,  transform the points to that crs.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert for the development of all these tools and for constantly helping newcomers